# How to create an custom share screen when receiving a share in a flutter app(or on Android and iOS native) like the pocket app?

Tags: android, ios, swift, flutter, kotlin

I want to show the screen of a custom app like a demo, not the default share sheet, when I click Share in an external app

I already checked the below issue and didn't understand it in that android answer
[How to make an overlay when sharing into app in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27084404/how-to-make-an-overlay-when-sharing-into-app-in-android)

It will be implemented in a flutter app, and answers on how to implement Android and iOS native are also welcome

### demo

[[demo gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUfvA.gif)]
[[demo gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uErrB.gif)]

[demo png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlpCJ.jpg)
[demo png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DhAj.jpg)

I tried using WindowManager to share sheet using Intent.ACTION_SEND in Android, but the important thing is that pocket app doesn't ask for systemAlertWindow permission
[What APIs are used to draw over other apps (like Facebook's Chat Heads)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15975988/what-apis-are-used-to-draw-over-other-apps-like-facebooks-chat-heads)

I want a custom screen to appear when sharing my app from outside, rather than simply floating my app on top of other apps.