# Is it possible set wrapContent attribute on view without parrent?

Tags: android, view, android-wrap-content

I have a simple button view, and set it as content view. Is it possible to resize this view programmaticly to "wrap_content"?

```
Button button = new Button(getContext());
button.setText("Some text");
setContentView(button);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not set `LayoutParams` for a view without parent.

Comment: Is thats mean I don't have any way to change view sizes witout wrapping this view in layout?

Comment: Yes, without layout your button can't display.

Comment: My button can display, and it have with and height equal to screen sizes, but seems android don't create some layout implicitly, because getParrent() or getLayoutParams() returns null

Comment: @VitaliZaharenko In fact your button in this case will added to a `Window` which is manage by `WindowManager`.  Read more: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22442702/1798031

Answer (score 1):

Set your attributes using the following code:

```
Button button = new Button(getContext());

LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
button.setLayoutParams(params);

button.setText("Some text");
setContentView(button);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use LinearLayout.LayoutParams with something like this:

```
Button button = new Button(getContext());

LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new   LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
button.setLayoutParams(params);
params.weight = 1.0f;
button.setText("Some text");
setContentView(button);
```